# Is there a way for itunes to display a total playtime column header?

Tags: itunes, mac, music

While play count is quite accurate in estimating how long I have listened to certain songs for, it isn't entirely precise. For example, if I have two songs, one that is 4:00 minutes that has been played 25 times and a song that is 5:00 minutes that has been played 21 times, if I sort my songs by play count the former song ranks higher. However, in terms of total playtime, the first song has only played for 6000 seconds, whereas the second has been played for 6300 seconds.

Assuming there are no tools which already provide that functionality, how can I accomplish this with AppleScript?

Comment: iTunes does not provide this column. I would be surprised if you were able to develop any sort of plugin that tracked it.

Comment: iTunes itself doesn't provide this, but you should be able to build something like this yourself either via AppleScript or by parsing the iTunes XML file directly.

Comment: That sounds promising. Are there any guides on getting started with this?

Comment: Also, thank you for the edit, patrix. It's helpful for getting used to the formatting of questions on SE.